# A program that, given a string, a width, and an empty string for ouput, centers the string in the ouput area.

Tags: c, string

The function is to return 1 if the formatting is successful and 0 if any errors, such as string length greater than width, are found. I'm getting errors though? What's wrong? I don't think I'm calling it right either...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int dummy, value = 0;

    formatString(value);

    scanf_s("%d",&dummy);
    return 0;
}

int formatString (char *in, 
              char *out, 
              int   width)
{
//Local Declarations
int spaces;
char *start;
char *walker;
int value;

spaces = (width – 1) – strlen(in);
if (spaces < 0)
{
    value = 0;
}
else
{
    start = out + (spaces / 2);
    for (walker = out; walker < start; walker++)
       *walker = ' ';
    strcpy (start, in);

    for (walker = out + strlen(out); 
         walker < out + width – 2; 
         walker++)
       *walker = ' ';
    *walker = ‘\0’;
}
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile at all. `formatString` is being called incorrectly. What output are you expecting? -1 until this information is provided. SO shouldn't be expected to get your code to compile, by the way.

Comment: Can't you do this with just `printf` by itself?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ill-formed beyond recognition. Your homework solution looks like this:

```
int str_center(char *out, int width, char *in)
{
    int offset;

    // compute and check offset
    offset = (width - strlen(in)) / 2;
    if (offset < 0)
            return -1;

    // initialize output buffer
    memset(out, ' ', width - 1);
    out[width - 1] = '\0';

    // write result
    memcpy(out + offset, in, strlen(in));
    return 0;
}
```

First, we compute the offset at which to copy the input string to the output string. This will be negative iff the input string is strictly greater than the output string; in that case, we'll bail out and return -1. Most developers use zero for success and non-zero for failure, since there's often only one way to succeed, but thousands to fail.

Then, we initialize the output buffer with spaces and properly terminate it with a null terminator.

Finally, we are using our offset to write the input string to the output string, starting at the desired position.

Note that we don't need to loop over any of the strings. `memset()` and `memcpy()` will do that for us, and maybe much more efficient. Also note that we just need one local variable. You're already using four local variables for such a trivial function. Try to keep the number of local variables small. If you can't do that, split the function. Otherwise, you won't be able to read your own code two weeks later. And judging from the result of your efforts, you're already having trouble reading it immediately.

Comment: Is it more like this?

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int dummy, value = 0;

 str_center(value);

 scanf_s("%d",&dummy);
 return 0;
}

int str_center(char *out, int width, char *in)
{
    int offset;

    // compute and check offset
    offset = (width - strlen(in)) / 2;
    if (offset < 0)
            return -1;

    // initialize output buffer
    memset(out, ' ', width - 1);
    out[width - 1] = '\0';

    // write result
    memcpy(out + offset, in, strlen(in));
    return 0;
}

I'm still not sure why I'm getting errors? I don't know how to call 'memset' and 'memcpy'